# R How to transform a for loop with recursive lag into a function?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, recursion, lag

I can compute a recursive variable with a for loop like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:10))

df$it <- NA
for(i in 1:length(df$V1)) {
  df$it <- 0.5*df$V1 + dplyr::lag(df$it, default = 0)
  }
df
```

But how can I do this with a function on the fly?
The following produces an error "C stack usage  15924032 is too close to the limit":

```
adstwm <- function(x){
  0.5*x + adstwm(dplyr::lag(x, default = 0))
  }
adstwm(df$V1)
```

I guess I need to define a stop for the process, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cumulative sum to achieve the desired result. This sums all preceding values in a vector which is effectively the same as your recursive loop:

```
df$it_2 <- cumsum(0.5*df$V1)
```

If you do want to make recursive function, for example to address the comment below you can include an if statement that will make it stop:

```
function_it <- function(vector, length) {
  if (length == 1) 0.5*vector[length]
  else 0.5*vector[length] + 0.1*function_it(vector, length-1)
}

df$it <- NA
for(i in 1:length(df$V1)) { 
  df$it[i] <- function_it(df$V1,i)
} 
df
```

However, you still need the for loop since the function is not vectorised so not sure if it really helps.

Comment: great!
But what if I only want a portion of the lag like:
 df$it <- NA
for(i in 1:length(df$V1)) {
  df$it <- 0.5*df$V1 + 0.1*dplyr::lag(df$it, default = 0)
}
df

?

Comment: In that case the cumsum() function will not work I am afraid. A recursive function could be a solution, I will edit my answer to include a way to make it stop.

Comment: I found a way to put the lagged for loop into the function, cp. my answer

Answer (score 0):

I can put the lagged for loop into the function without recursing the function:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:10))
func.it2 <- function(x){
  df$it2 <- NA
  for(i in 1:length(df$V1)) {
    df$it2 <- 0.5*df$V1 + 0.1*dplyr::lag(df$it2, default = 0)
  }
  df$it2
  }
func.it2(df$V1)
df
df$it2 <- func.it2(df$V1)
df
```

That works. But why is df$it2 not available as a variable in df until I declare it (second last line) although it was already available in the for loop (line 5)?

Comment: variables inside a function are not part of the global environment, they exist only in the function. So the column it2 is 'temporarily' created and the rest of the code in the function can access it, but it will not be created in the global environment.

Comment: Merci @pieterbons, understood.